# Cardinality of the set of $C^1$ functions with these properties

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all continuously differentiable real valued functions defined on the real line. Define
>   $$A=\{f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})\mid f(0)=0,\,f(1)=1,\,|f'(x)|\leq 1/2\,\text{ for all }\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
>   where $f'$ denotes the derivative of the function $f$. Pick out the true statement:
>
> (a) $A$ is an empty set.
>   (b) $A$ is a finite and non-empty set.
>   (c) $A$ is an infinite set.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBy5A.png))

I don't know which result from analysis I should apply here, please give me some hints or remark

Comment: [Mean value theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

Comment: Yeah, I unthinkingly overstepped "hints or remark."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, if $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, then there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that 
$$
f'(c)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=1,
$$
which is impossible if $|f'(x)|\leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  So the set is empty.